# C# winforms stuck on Loading with ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms

can anyone tell me why my progress bar is just not moving? The forms title is just stuck at 'Loading' and the progress bar is stuck at 0%, it does finish perfectly fine and opens up the new form, but the progress bar doesn't move, and doesn't color any of the bar in green?

This process should take 10 seconds, so each second should make 10% of the bar green, no?

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WordList_Master
{
    public partial class Loading : Form
    {
        public Loading()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int lol = 100;
            while (lol > 0)
            {
                lol--;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form = new Form1();
            Form.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to report your progress inside that while loop:  `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(lol);`  Not sure why you are going in reverse on your progress.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to actually *report the progress*:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int lol = 100;        
    while (lol > 0)
    {
        // report
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100-lol);

        lol--;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

See [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress(v=vs.110).aspx). This method raises the `ProgressChanged` event associated with your background worker (invoking the handler on your UI thread).

---

And just realised you also forgot to register the event handlers:

```
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you hook up the event handlers somewhere and that you actually report the Progress as suggested by @René Vogt. This should work:

```
public partial class Loading : Form
{
    public Loading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
        progressBar1.Value = 0;

        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int lol = 100;
        while (lol > 0)
        {
            lol--;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100 - lol);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form Form = new Form1();
        Form.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, forgot about the handlers. +1